# Paypal Interruptus - Wordpress w/ CiviCRM 4.7.1

Tags: upgrade, paypal, 4.7, pending

Wordpress 4.4.2
CiviCRM Just upgraded from 4.6.10 to 4.7.1 last week.

Ever since we've upgraded, CiviCRM allows payments to be made via PayPal, but event registrations and membership renewals are now always marked as "Pending (incomplete transaction)". We have to manually go to PayPal, check whether they've actually paid, confirm and then edit the pending flag manually so that the transaction shows as complete in CiviCRM.

Additionally, email confirmations from CiviCRM are not going out.

This is causing much more work than we had to do last week before we updated to CiviCRM 4.7.1

Test event registrations and renewals work as expected. Live ones don't.

On the off chance that 4.7.2 has a fix, I've just upgraded successfully to the latest version. Until I see some renewals or event registrations, I won't know if that's fixed it.

I'd be grateful if someone can tell me if 4.7.2 had the fix or if this is something outside the scope of 4.7.2.

(see image below)

Cheers,

Chris

[image: pending-incomplete transation]

Comment: There isn't enough full coverage regression testing. We should have stuck with the version from about a year ago.. the features we needed seemed to work then.

Comment: I wish I knew enough about the code to make a reasonable contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer now is to upgrade from 4.7.1 to 4.7.4 or better.
Apparently a number of paypal processes were corrected after this and other posts on civicrm.stackexchange.com brought the bug to light.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means that paypal doesn't ping back properly your civi to let it know if it processed properly the card. Unfortunately, they are a lot of reasons to get that call not working, either because paypal try to IPN elsewhere, with a different format than expected or that something is wrong on how we process it (given it broke after an upgrade, the most likely option)

Can you check on the log if you have any error that might clarify what is the issue?

Comment: I have checked the wp error log. There are 10 items on the log, some of them spanning back to October of last year, none of them involving CiviCRM.

Comment: Paypal recognizes the payments as processed. CiviCRM is not sending out Confirmation emails. Also, the upgrade to 4.7.2 does not seem to have fixed the error. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Additional information - the person who administers civicrm now suggests she may have made some changes to an event about the same time, but the change was only for a specific event, and only to create a personal campaign page. She has since removed the personal campaign page, and we're still seeing the same results. Also, it's not just campaigns but memberships and member renewals that are affected with "Pending, incomplete transaction", so the problem is likely something not necessarily related to this specific event.

Comment: I have the same issue with CiviCRM 4.7.2 on the latest WordPress stable. Paypal IPN http requests are received and entries created in civicrm_system_log, but the error logs show "Could not find payment processor for contribution record: N". I suspect that http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9753/paypal-recurring-transactions-are-broken-in-4-7 is related.

Comment: What kind of WordPress install do you have? I have just fixed one part of the problem in multisite and multi-network situations: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18099

Comment: Mine is a single-site install. Like Logan Bear, I have several inactive payment processors that only kick in when the date is right. I'm not sure the jira link applies in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a fix that works for me, but I cannot guarantee that it won't have consequences for other transactions. A fully audited fix for this needs the involvement of people who know the code a lot better than me. Having said that, you can try the following:

Change this:

```
throw new CRM_Core_Exception
```

to this:

```
CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message
```

in this file on line 177 for WordPress:

> /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/BaseIPN.php

or this file on line 178 for Joomla:

> /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/BaseIPN.php

There's a ticket on Jira that seems to be relevant here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18107

Comment: This would only be a temporary fix though, right? Because we're just hiding the action on this error in the log -- and any other future-introduced flaw in this part of the code? Surely this is not a permanent fix.

Comment: Indeed. As I said, "a fully audited fix for this needs the involvement of people who know the code a lot better than me" :-)

Comment: Subscribing. This resolved a nearly identical issue with one of my Joomla installs. I'll be watching for a bugfix or more info.