# Paypal Recurring Transactions Are Broken in 4.7

Tags: paypal, recurring-contributions

When posting a recurring transaction with PayPal (offline and online), we're getting a 'Transaction ID not set' Payment Processor error.  The payment is created in Paypal.

Checking Civi log file, on offline transactions, getting:

```
[info] Could not find payment processor for contribution record: #######
```

For the online transaction, the log file has:

```
[info] contributionRecur could not be loaded
[info] Contribution record updated successfully
[info] Receipt sent
[info] Success: Database updated
```

This problem seems to have started with the 4.7 upgrade.

Even recurring transactions coming from Paypal are giving the same '[info] Could not find payment processor for contribution record:' error.

[Site profile settings](https://mycivi.org/profile/snapshot/Nxk3j-4jJZ8-VZ2jl-7x9Bx)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with CiviCRM 4.7.2 on the latest WordPress stable with non-recurring transactions. I suspect that http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9730/paypal-interruptus-wordpress-w-civicrm-4-7-1 is related.

Comment: I found the problem and if I knew how to make a patch I would.  The issue is found in the PayPalProIPN.php file.  It attempts to find the Paypal payment processor, but doesn't limit the search to active processors.  I had an old PayPal account.  I added the parameter 'is_active = 1' and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the info Logan, I'll see what I can do. I have a two Paypal processors, one for testing one for live - perhaps I'm seeing the same thing as you.

Comment: Just ran into this issue after upgrades to 4.7.1 and 4.7.2.  @Logan Bear, can you give more precise details on where to try your code in that file?

Comment: I found the file at /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php. However, I'm not entirely sure where the parameter `is_active = 1` should go. I don't see examples commented out, nor `is_active = 0` default setting anywhere in the file. I'd be grateful for suggestions.

Comment: Ah, to be clear you're using Paypal Pro. I presume you're referring to the `civicrm_api3()` call?

Comment: @ChristianWach, yes I added a line 'is_active=1,' to the api3 call on PaymentProcessor 'getvalue'.  In my situation, I have two PayPal processors - one enabled one disabled.  Since the disabled was first, the system failed.  By adding one line, Civi selected the only active Paypal processor and it worked.  What's odd is the payment processor being used in already in the contribution_recur table.  But since the IPN sets this variable before checking the recur table, the value in the recur table is ignored.  If Civi would take the value from the recur table, this whole problem would disappear.

Comment: I posted a slightly different approach to the issue - but I'm not sure if it'll fix your situation. Essentially I can't figure out why finding the payment processor should trigger a fatal error. the following fixes things for me: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9730/paypal-interruptus-wordpress-w-civicrm-4-7-1/9927#9927

Comment: We are having this issue on our site, CiviCRM 4.7.2, Drupal.  I did delete unused payment processors (e.g. an old fiscal sponsor account that we no longer use), and the problem persists of "transaction id not set" error when setting up an auto-renew membership.

Comment: Our inactive payment processors kick in when the next change in event pricing happens, so I can't delete them. Which numbered line is affected as shown in github: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/BaseIPN.php and what is the before and after code the code on/around that line?

Comment: Opened a Jira issue here: [Recurring PayPal transactions fail with 'Transaction ID not set'](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18140)

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which version of CiviCRM you're using. There were some fixes related to PayPal in 4.7.13, in particular look at [CRM-18483](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18483) If you're not up on at least 4.7.13, it would be worth upgrading.

(Edited to correct a typo)